# nginx upstream and fail_timeout

Tags: nginx

The definition from the official nginx documentation on `fail_timeout` states the following:

```
* the time during which the specified number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the server should happen to consider the server unavailable;
* and the period of time the server will be considered unavailable.
```

My question is, what is the timeout for one individual request after which the request is marked unsuccessful, and how is this timeout value defined?

If `max_fails=3` and `fail_timeout=120`, does this mean that request is unsuccessful if it timeouts after 120/3 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is stated in the documentation of the [max_fails](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#max_fails) parameter:

> What is considered an unsuccessful attempt is defined by the proxy_next_upstream, fastcgi_next_upstream, uwsgi_next_upstream, scgi_next_upstream, and memcached_next_upstream directives.

If you read on in these documents, you will find different timeouts which can happen: `*_connect_timeout`, `*_send_timeout`, `*_read_timeout` etc.

So there is not one single timeout which applies to an individual request but different timeouts depending on the state of the request. The `fail_timeout` and `max_fails` parameter merely state that if there are a given number of failures during a given time, the server is considered unavailable.